# jQuery fadeIn on a table causing rows that I want to be hidden to be displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am calling a fade in on a `table` which contains several smaller divs in it. The whole schema boils down to this:

```
<div id="resources" class="no-select">
    <h1 class="sectionTitle">Resources</h1>
    <table id="resourceGrid" class="pointer">

        <tr id='tierIResources'>
        </tr>

        <tr id="tierIIResources">
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

CSS boils down to this

```
tr#tierIIResources, div#resources, {
     display: none;
}
```

When I call `.fadeIn()` on `$('#resources')`, it ends up displaying both `tierI` and `tierII` resources. I would like to make it so only `tierI` is displayed. I can get around it by calling `('#tierIIResources').css('display', 'none)` but this is not optimal, and I would like to know how to do it purely with CSS or without the need for an additional function.

Thank you!

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and its working fine.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#resources").fadeIn();
    });
```

```css
 #tierIIResources, #resources {
         display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div id="resources" class="no-select">
        <h1 class="sectionTitle">Resources</h1>
        <table id="resourceGrid" class="pointer">
    
            <tr id='tierIResources'>
              <td>tierIResources</td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr id="tierIIResources">
              <td>tierIIResources</td>
            </tr>
    
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is a working codepen link.

[Example codepen](https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/VXbvrx/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your post, or I thought it was till I discovered that was the problem, you posted

```
tr#tierIIResources, div#resources, {
     display: none;
}
```

with an exta comma at the end, but it's not like the comma should not be there, it's that you are missing `tr#tierIResourcesf` from that selector, it should be:

```
tr#tierIIResources, div#resources, tr#tierIResourcesf{
    display: none;
}
```

then it'll work. Let me know

```js
$('#resources').fadeIn();
```

```css
tr#tierIIResources, div#resources, tr#tierIResourcesf{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resources" class="no-select">
            <h1 class="sectionTitle">Resources</h1>
            <table id="resourceGrid" class="pointer">
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="tierIIResources"><td>d</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id='tierIResourcesf'><td>a</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```